# nonlocal for a method inside a class in Python 3.6.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have searched this but I can't find anything. In the [Python documentation 9.2.1](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html) there is an example given, using a function `scope_test()`.

```
def scope_test():
    def do_local():
        spam = "local spam"

    def do_nonlocal():
        nonlocal spam
        spam = "nonlocal spam"

    def do_global():
        global spam
        spam = "global spam"

    spam = "test spam"
    do_local()
    print("After local assignment:", spam)
    do_nonlocal()
    print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam)
    do_global()
    print("After global assignment:", spam)

scope_test()
print("In global scope:", spam)
```

When I change it to a `class` and run it, I get:

```
SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'spam' found
```

I figure `'nonlocal'` does not work for methods inside class, but it works just find for functions inside a function. All the answer I found online are for functions, not classes.

- Why does nonlocal not work for classes?
- Is there a way around?

Answer (score 1):

`nonlocal` certainly works for methods inside a class, you just need to nest the functions in a method (I'm using a staticmethod here):

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def scope_test():
        def do_local():
            spam = "local spam"

        def do_nonlocal():
            nonlocal spam
            spam = "nonlocal spam"

        def do_global():
            global spam
            spam = "global spam"

        spam = "test spam"
        do_local()
        print("After local assignment:", spam)
        do_nonlocal()
        print("After nonlocal assignment:", spam)
        do_global()
        print("After global assignment:", spam)

Foo.scope_test()
print("In global scope:", spam)
```

Making `scope_test` a class doesn't introduce the nesting required for `nonlocal` to work. You'll still need the nesting.

Answer (score 1):

The lexical scoping which is put on display in that example only works for function namespaces. Imagine if this were to work in a class - then all of the class methods would be capable of accessing class attributes directly, instead of through the `self` parameter or class name as things actually work.

In other words, the namespace of a class **does not introduce an enclosing scope** for methods within the class, and this also prevents `nonlocal` from finding class body-level bindings.